# Find difference between two window forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this two `xml` files which are identical in structure and the code for parsing one is here:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var root = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\am\Desktop\_albana\ev_projects.xml");
        var controlElements = root.Descendants("CONTROL");

        var root1 = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\am\Desktop\_albana\ev_projects_modified.xml");
        var controlElements1 = root.Descendants("CONTROL");


        int labelCounter = 1;
        foreach (var element in controlElements)
        {
            var labelId = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");
            var textBoxName = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");


            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");

            label.Left = 10;
            label.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

            textBox.Left = 120;
            textBox.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;
            textBox.Text = (string)element.Attribute("ATTRIBUTE");


            this.Controls.Add(label);
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);

            labelCounter++;
        }


        foreach (var element in controlElements1)
        {
            var labelId1 = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");
            var textBoxName1 = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");


            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = (string)element.Attribute("LABEL_D");

            label1.Left = 10;
            label1.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;

            TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

            textBox1.Left = 120;
            textBox1.Top = (labelCounter + 1) * 20;
            textBox1.Text = (string)element.Attribute("ATTRIBUTE");


            this.Controls.Add(label1);
            this.Controls.Add(textBox1);

            labelCounter++;
        }



    }
```

So as you see i have two `xml` files i load into a form, i need to compare `labelId1` with `labelId` if they are the same i see the respective  `textBox1`.Text and  `textBox`.Text, if they are different i should highlight them.
Any idea?

Comment: I think it's funny you are comparing two forms when your first and last names are the same, surely you should have a good idea?!

Comment: well, of course i need to compare them, using an if or where maybe using arrays, but i don't know how to implement that, i know it's not difficult but i'm new...

Comment: How about using `Reflections`?
You could search within any objects for string propertys and compare them.

Comment: Reflections is a bit too much for me, as i am a beginner

Comment: i think i could do it if i compare directly within te second foreach

Comment: Love your poor man's implementation of `WPF` `XAML`. Have you searched the interweb for "diff xml"? How exactly do you want to actually display the output, because its non-trivial. I would suggest that you just run the two files through a simple diff tool...

Comment: well Aron, i'm new so my goal is not to find the perfect solution but to find a solution, so i need to output both files as i do, the second file i need to compare it with the first one, if there is any change, if there is i hightlight the textbox color

Comment: @SebastianL how does `Reflection` help? You only push the problem to "How do I compare two object trees." Which is a much more difficult problem (since there is non-obvious behavior for each part of the problem (member wise compare or reference equal, which properties should you compare, etc etc).

Comment: @AniAni in general any problem space which requires "parsing" a language is a hard problem. In this case you need to understand concepts like tokenization, you need to understand the grammar of XML. For example, if I add a single 'space' in your xml, how do you handle that? How about a line break? It isn't EASY to highlight your target text, because you need to match the "diff" to the target text. I knew you were a newbie, that was why I was trying to steer you away from hard problems.

Comment: hmm, well, yes, you're right, i know what i'm looking for, my problem is i just want to build the algorithm and then get in details about spaces and so on

Comment: @Aron you sure are right, i just thought Ani Ani wanted to compare he Object trees because of the Headline. But comparing the two XML files is much easier, as you said ^^

Comment: @AniAni Your problem can be divided into two solved problems. XML parsing (use LinqToXML, or XDoc) and comparison of Trees. Just write a program to read the xml files into Linq To XML, then recursively compare each node by element name and attribute. Easy. Takes a lot of time to get right though. However, the highlighting part. Forget it. Get a proper XML Diff tool, its not worth it.